# filter Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
q = {"It", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", "it", "was", "the", "worst", "of", "times"}
```

write an expression to return

```
wasworsttimes
```

without using any character or string literals.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: This sounds like homework.  What have you tried?

Comment: That isn't really a hash. A hash is a map of key-value pairs. Ruby will evaluate it as a hash, taking every odd element as a key and every subsequent element as the value, but it's not clear if that's what you meant here.

Comment: @bnaul, that is a valid Ruby hash literal.

Comment: Its a question from one of my sample exam papers the professor has put on... I'm actually stuck with this...

Comment: yea its a valid Hash literal...

Comment: @bnaul: `{a,b,c,d}` is the same as `{a => b, c => d}` in ruby 1.8.

Comment: I tried every creative way i can... even tried with patterns ;)(of course i'm a noob)

Comment: @matthew-flaschen @sepp2k I know, I think my comment even says that...I just wanted to clarify since the rest of the question didn't indicate that he knew that.

Comment: Am I the only one who has no idea what the question is here? What relationship does the hash have to the string "answer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the hash should be `{"it", "was",...}` (lower case `i` at the beginning).

Then this literal will create the following hash `{"it"=>"was", "the"=>"worst", "of"=>"times"}`.

Note that the words you're supposed to extract are the value of the hash. So you can just use `Hash`'s `values` method to get them and `Array`'s `join` method to turn the array of values into a string.